# Why IB is not giving options to insert @IBOutlet or @IBAction in custom Swift file?

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, xcode7

I have created a new cocoa file which is subclass of `NSObject` and conforms to `NSTableView` protocols. When I try to connect an `IBOutlet` or `IBAction` from a `NSButton` in IB, no options pop up. I tried connecting both way

```
import Cocoa

class TestTableController: NSObject, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var button:NSButton!
}
```

and then connecting it but same result. I am able to make successful connection from `AppDelegate` file.

Her are some screenshots:

[image: manually connection from self property]

[image: another try]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an NSObject (or whichever you prefer) and then select it as a Custom Class:

[image]

Then you should be able to connect it to your button.

Comment: It worked but why can't I make connection by ctrl+drag to file itself. Also now when I try to instantiate this class from AppDelegate and call a function which hides the button, I get an error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, the error is obvious but why is it nil. How can I use this button.

Comment: I didn't design Xcode, so ask Apple why ctrl + drag doesn't work. The nil warning is likely because you still have an IB connection to something that no longer exists, or isn't connected properly.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, apology if my question offend you.

Comment: @jyt: You're welcome! and no offense taken at all. There are other ways to connect classes with IB elements (eg. programmatically, etc), although when mouse dragging connections objects still need to be able to associate with their class somehow...